# Firebase Simulator denies read

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have firestore database with following rules:

#### Firebase Rules

```
service cloud.firestore {

    function signedIn() {
      return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null;
  }

  function isAuthorized(accountId) {
    return signedIn() && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/accounts/$(accountId)/users/$(request.auth.uid));
  }

  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid} {
      allow read, write: if signedIn() && uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
    match /users/{uid}/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if signedIn() && uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
    match /accounts/{accountId} {
      allow read: if isAuthorized(accountId);
    }
    match /accounts/{accountId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isAuthorized(accountId);
    }
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Database Records

Existing Records in DB

1. /users/*u123*
2. /accounts/**axyz**/users/*u123*

#### Problem

I would expect a user logged in with uid: *u123* have read access to /accounts/**axyz**
However, Simulator just throws error `Simulated read denied` without giving any hints (which line/rule is causing the failure/denial..)

#### Question??

1. What is problem with these rules?
2. Why Simulator can't give the reason?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

#### Update 1

If I replace function call `isAuthorized(accountId)` with the function body like below, then it works perfectly.

```
match /accounts/{accountId} {
  allow read: if signedIn() && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/accounts/$(accountId)/users/$(request.auth.uid));
}
match /accounts/{accountId}/{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if signedIn() && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/accounts/$(accountId)/users/$(request.auth.uid));
}
```

So it is working like this. But Still wondering why invoking function fails.

Comment: Does it work if you run actual app code against the rules?  The simulator in the console is not 100% accurate sometimes.

Comment: Can't test with Applicaton yet, but as mentioned in **Update 1** if inline the function `isAuthorized` then it works from the simulator.